# Removing options from select using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, dom, dom-manipulation

Suppose I have a Select element:

```
<select>
    <option value="Name 1">Simon</option>
    <option value="Name 2">Frank</option>
    <option value="Name 3">Bob</option>
    <option value="Name 4">Alex</option>
</select>
```

And I have an array of strings, suppose:

```
["Simon", "Alex"]
```

How do I remove from the DOM (using jQuery) every `option` element that does **not** have a **inner html** value contained in the above list? For example, given the above list of inner html values (`["Simon", "Alex"]`), I would like to remove only the `<option value="Name 2">Frank</option>` and `<option value="Name 3">Bob</option>` elements, so that the final `select` element would look like:

```
<select>
    <option value="Name 1">Simon</option>
    <option value="Name 4">Alex</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:

```
var list = ["Simon", "Alex"]; // Say your list is this

$(function(){

    $('select option').filter(function () { //Use filter on options
       return $.inArray(this.innerHTML, list) == -1 // get the option text which is not in the array
    }).remove(); //Remove them
});
```

#### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/H2bEq/)

Refer

- [$.inArray()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/)
- [filter()](http://api.jquery.com/filter/)

Meanwhile instead of $.inArray you can also use ecmascript-5 spec [Array.prototype.indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf)

`return list.indexOf(this.innerHTML) == -1`

Answer (score 2):

Another way is to clear the Select and re-populate it using array or JSON formatted data structure:

```
// JSON formatted data structure
list = { "1": "Simon", "2" : "Alex" };

// Removes all options for the select box
$('select option').remove();

// Add option to the select box from list
$.each(list, function(key, value) {   
     $('select')
         .append($("<option></option>")
         .attr("value",key)
         .text(value)); 
});
```

Above example is using JSON fromat (which I recommend as it's always faster than Arrays). If you still want to use Array just replace the JSON list with your array list (i.e. `var list = ["Simon", "Alex"];`) and you will get same results.